# Solve $\log_4 ( 16^{100})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do i evaluate

$$\log_4 { 16^{100}}$$

After finding the $\log_4$ of $16$ which is $2$, how do I get $200$ and why? Wouldn't the $2$ be squared by $100$? Or wouldn't the $2$ be on the other side of the equal sign $100 = 2$.

Can't understand how the answer is $200$. Only way that can happen is if you multiply $2$ by $100$.

Explain. Remember I am a precalculus student.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember we can take the power out and put it in front of the logarithm, so $\log_4 16^{100}=100\,\log_4 16$.

Now $\log_4 16$ is: "to what power do I have to raise $4$ to get $16$. That is $2$, so $\log_4 16=2$.

Hence, $\log_4 16^{100}=100\cdot2=200$.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation that followed the rules of Logarithm.

Answer (score 3):

Think $4^{?}=16^{100}$.

Then $16^{100}=(4^2)^{100}=4^{200}$

Comment: Does not follow the properties of logarithm, as in the explicit laws.

Comment: It follows the definition of logarithms, and uses laws of exponents to solve problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\log_x y^z=z \log_x y.
$$

Thus, $\log_4 16^{100}=100\log_4 16=100\cdot2=200$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
16^{100} = (4^2)^{100} = 4^{200}.
$$